# restrict visiting user/1 path for all users except admin

Tags: 7, users

I would like to add a condition that users are not able to visit admin profile using user/1 in url. (not even if url contains alias).
What would be the easiest way of doing that? I do not want to install additional module just for this task. Thank you.

Comment: you could use a page redirect using hook_page_alter in a theme's template.php, or you will need to use a module if you want it theme independant - that's how Drupal is designed.

Comment: @Geoff I have no problem to add code to template.php Any snippet available?

Answer (score 0):

In template.php of you theme:

```
function NAMEOFYOURTHEME_preprocess_page($vars) {
  if ($_GET['q'] == "user/1")
  {
    drupal_goto("ANY PAGE"); //Example <front> for the homepage
  }
}
```

Clear cache and enjoy :)

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in page.tpl.php

```
global $user;
global $base_url;
$uid=$user->uid;
if(agr(0)=='user' && arg(1)==1)
{
if($uid!=1)
{
drupal_goto($base_url);
}
}
```

OR

```
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_page($vars) {
  if ($_GET['q'] == "user/1")
  {
    $usr = user_load(arg(1));
    if(!in_array('administrator',$usr->roles) ){
         drupal_goto("ANY PAGE"); //Example <front> for the homepage
    }
  }
 }
```

Hope this will work